# Filtering the required data from Firebase based on the button selection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have two activities, one(MainActivity) where there is an option of selecting the Category of event you want to see, and the second activity(EventView) shows you those particular events based on your selection. The category options are:
Arch 
Art 
Finance
Science

In the next activity, I want the data from Firebase to come in the form of a recycler view based on the category I select, however all my data from Firebase is being called. I added a query next to my databaseReference, using orderByChild, to get my required data.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.admin.trialforevents;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button b1, b2, b3, b4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.archBttn);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.artBttn);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scienceBttn);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.financeBttn);

        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button Selected !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EventView.class);


    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.archBttn:
            String arch = "Architecture";
            i.putExtra("Category", arch);
            break;

        case R.id.artBttn:
            String art = "Art";
            i.putExtra("Category", art);
            break;

        case R.id.scienceBttn:
            String science = "Science";
            i.putExtra("Category", science);
            break;

        case R.id.financeBttn:
            String fin = "Finance";
            i.putExtra("Category", fin);
            break;
    }
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.trialforevents.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/archBttn"
        android:text="Arch"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Art "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/archBttn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/archBttn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/archBttn"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:id="@+id/artBttn" />

    <Button
        android:text="Finance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/financeBttn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/artBttn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/artBttn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/artBttn"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Science"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/financeBttn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/financeBttn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/financeBttn"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:id="@+id/scienceBttn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

EventView.java

```
package com.example.admin.trialforevents;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class EventView extends AppCompatActivity{

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_view);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ApprovedEvents");


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.request_EventList);

        //Avoid unnecessary layout passes by setting setHasFixedSize to true
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //Select the type of layout manager you would use for your recyclerView
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        final String event_cat  = getIntent().getStringExtra("Category");
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, RequestViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, RequestViewHolder>(
                Event.class,
                R.layout.event_list_row,
                RequestViewHolder.class,
                databaseReference.orderByChild(event_cat)
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(RequestViewHolder viewHolder, Event model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                    viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                    viewHolder.setCategory(model.getCategory());
                    viewHolder.setLocation(model.getLocation());
                    viewHolder.setPrice(model.getPrice());
                    viewHolder.setImageUrl(getApplicationContext(), model.getImageUrl());
                viewHolder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(EventView.this, "Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public static class RequestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        ImageView imageButton;


        public RequestViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            imageButton = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_image);
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            TextView a_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_title);
            a_title.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            TextView a_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_desc);
            a_desc.setText(desc);
        }

        public void setLocation(String location) {
            TextView a_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_location);
            a_desc.setText(location);
        }


        public void setCategory(String category) {
            TextView a_category = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_category);
                a_category.setText(category);
        }

        public void setPrice(String price) {
            TextView a_price = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_price);
            a_price.setText(price);
        }

        public void setImageUrl(Context ctx, String imageUrl) {
            ImageView a_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(imageUrl).into(a_image);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_event_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.trialforevents.EventView">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/request_EventList"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Event.java

```
package com.example.admin.trialforevents;

public class Event {

    private String title, desc, location, category, price, imageUrl;

    public Event(String title, String imageUrl, String price, String category, String location, String desc) {
        this.title = title;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.price = price;
        this.category = category;
        this.location = location;
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    public Event(){

    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

}
```

event_list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/request_category"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Category will come here"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="191dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/request_location"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Location will come here"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price will come here"
        android:id="@+id/request_price"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="275dp"
        android:id="@+id/request_image"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/request_title"
        android:text="Title will come here "
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/request_desc"
        android:text="Desc will come here "
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the FireBaseRecyclerAdapter while mentioning datareference as an argument, use a query like:

```
databaseReference.orderByChild("category").equalTo(event_cat)
```

This will call only the category of data that is required.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it!

Everything is fine, except your Switch: after each **Case**, you should provide a **Break**.

The way it is written now will always cause the last case to be called, which is "Finance" in your case.

Did this for you:

```
switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.archBttn:
        String arch = "Architecture";
        i.putExtra("Category", arch);
        break;

    case R.id.artBttn:
        String art = "Art";
        i.putExtra("Category", art);
        break;

    case R.id.scienceBttn:
        String science = "Science";
        i.putExtra("Category", science);
        break;

    case R.id.financeBttn:
        String fin = "Finance";
        i.putExtra("Category", fin);
        break;
}
```

Side note: your code is beautifully written :)

Comment: Hey thanks, it worked but I yet am facing difficulties getting data from Firebase based on what category I select.
Thanks for the side note:)

Comment: Sorry for missing that one: I think your issue is coming from this line of code (at EventView.java):
    **if(model.getCategory() == event_cat)**

In Java, you should use the **.equals** function for String comparisons. Took me a lot of time to figure this out myself.. but the operator "==" simply does not work with strings. Try this out: **if(model.getCategory().equals(event_cat))**

Comment: I tried using that but it's yet not working and showing me the same layout file of event_list_row.xml